# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_model.pkl'

Tags: python, pickle, streamlit

I have created a `.pkl` file in Jupyter notebook as the following:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(rfc, open('new_model.pkl', 'wb'))
```

This file is saved in the folder I am working in.

I am using Spyder to deploy my web application, the code is as follows:

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import string
import pickle

model = pickle.load(open('new_model.pkl','rb'))
```

When launching streamlit I am getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_model.pkl'
```

Comment: i am getting file not found error when lanching streamlit in my browser however not getting any errors in Spyder to say the file cannot be found

Comment: Are you running your script in the same folder that you ran the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, i am getting no errors in Spyder when clicking 'run'. I have altered the file name and once i change it to an incorrect file name, i get ' file not found, in spyder. It is once i try and run the app on my browser i am getting this error. Do you have LinkedIn or something i can send you screenshots over to help resolve as this is very confusing as to why it isnt working